# Xamarin Forms not displaying images in MVVMCross MvxContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm not able to view any local image in my pages. Using android as a reference, the images are correctly placed in the Resources/Drawable subfolders, but even using the default "icon.png" nothing shows up.

Here is my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvx:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
                     xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                     x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
                     BackgroundImage="icon.png">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <Image Source="icon.png"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</mvx:MvxContentPage>
```

Here are the files:

[image: Image files location]

In the build output I get the following messages:

```
[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: icon.png

[0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: icon.png
```

I suspect the problem is related to the use of mvxContentPage, because changing to a simple ContentPage and using Gorilla player for previewing the page the image shows up as intended.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I've not really found a solution, but I've moved to FreshMVVM from mvvmcross and the problem has not shown up.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete everything under your **(...).Android\bin** folder. VS will recreate everything and this time will include new images.